# How to compile several Foundation versions with Codekit 1 AND Codekit 2?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, codekit

I use Codekit 1 with Foundation (at the time of development current versions 4.3 - 5.1) and the required Ruby gems of Sass and Compass for older but still ongoing projects. I now purchased Codekit 2 to use the built-in Sass/Compass versions and bower installs for current and future projects. And for all it's awesomeness ;-)

Unfortunately Codekit 2 throws just one definitive error:

> Could not compile ... seems that you have older installs of
>   Sass/Compass ... you have to uninstall those so that Codekit's own
>   Sass/Compass versions can be compiled.

Googling for a solution I found https://github.com/bdkjones/codekit2/issues/286 , explaining that it's either ... or. Seems like I could either use Codekit 1 to update the old projects OR Codekit 2 to develop new ones. But not both, at least not on the same machine, or at least not without constantly installing and uninstalling Ruby gems all day. Since I need to update the older projects from time to time, I still need the older Compass and Sass Ruby gems permanently on my machine, next to Codekit 2.

There has to be a way to let Codekit 1 and 2 play along nicely, yes? Or how do you guys manage your different Foundation/Compass/Sass/Codekit versions?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, old friend of mine pointed me to a command line tool called RVM (https://rvm.io/).

With RVM you can manage different ruby versions, and within them different gemsets containing exactly those gems you would need for a certain project. You can switch them on and off as needed, which solves my problem of using Codekit 1 (RVM with custom project gemsets) together with Codekit 2 (on-board Sass/Compass).

There is even a GUI app for RVM called JewelryBox (https://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/).

Works for me!